# Get youtube download link url_encoded_fmt_stream_map

Tags: php, youtube

I am using preg_match_all to get the Youtube video links from a Youtube video page, and put them in Array, but I don't get any result.

```
preg_match_all('/url_encoded_fmt_stream_map\=(.*)/', $html, $matches);
```

is there a problem in the syntax of first parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use '**=**', you need to use '**:**' instead (If you look at the souce, you see: **"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map":**)

So you can use this:

```
preg_match('/url_encoded_fmt_stream_map(.*?);/', $html, $matches);   
$matches= substr($matches[0], 30, -1);
```

Here we delete the last '**;**' and the first '**"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map":**'.